# PHP Username/Password Security

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm creating a login script for a website I'm developing. At the moment I have the usernames and passwords hard-coded into the script. i.e.

```
$usersAndPasses = array(
    'username1' => 'password1',
    'username2' => 'password2'
)
```

and so on

I was wondering if this is any less secure than placing them in a MySQL database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not less secure ... unless of course there is file injection.  However, it will also be a *lot* slower than querying the database if you have lots of members (which you would currently have to add in manually).

Answer (score 3):

No. It is not less secure, unless someone steals your sources.